# temporary removing device /partition from RAID5 - getting "Device or resource busy"

Tags: software-raid

Here is a current state of my RAID5:
And it is rebuilding....

```
/dev/md10:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Dec 19 13:28:26 2021
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 511667200 (487.96 GiB 523.95 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 102333440 (97.59 GiB 104.79 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue Jan  4 02:55:13 2022
             State : clean, degraded, recovering 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 6
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : resync

    Rebuild Status : 2% complete

              Name : qz-desktop:10
              UUID : 9086174e:91b50e01:09a7fda1:eba8b0ad
            Events : 4098

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259       25        0      active sync   /dev/sdf16
       1     259       26        1      active sync   /dev/sdf17
       3     259       27        2      active sync   /dev/sdf18
       4       8        7        3      active sync   /dev/sda7
       5       8       83        4      active sync   /dev/sdf3
       6     259       32        5      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdf23
```

For test purposes I am trying remove device / partition

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md10 --fail /dev/sdf3 --verbose
```

then I am receiving this

```
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/sdf3:  Device or resource busy
```

I understand I need to "kill" the process keeping the device busy.

Can somebody **help me with EXACT commands**
how to find the unwanted process ?
how to use "kill" to stop such process?

I have read some posts doing the above but not sure how to
implement them without totally destroying the RAID5 -
I just want to temporary remove ONE device / partition.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you accepted answers on your other questions people might be more interested in answering these newer ones?

Comment: I am not sure what is your aim, but if you have a degraded RAID5 array, removing a disk will render the array unusable. A RAID5 can support only 1 disk off (and the disk under reconstruction doesn’t count).

Comment: Please read the original post - I am not asking for evaluations of RAID  I am asking how to remove the device.