# how to "unbusy" /dev/sdx?

Tags: ubuntu

I have found another thread , but it is old so I am posting...
It recommends "lsof" to find the blocking ( make busy) process
It hints I can use "dev/sdf23 " but it is not a file.

Any other way to "unbusy " /dev/sdc ?

```
qy@qy-desktop:~$ lsof +f -- /dev/sdf23
lsof: not a file system: /dev/sdf23
lsof 4.93.2
 latest revision: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof
 latest FAQ: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/00FAQ
 latest (non-formatted) man page: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/Lsof.8
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-E] [+|-e s] [+|-f[gG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
qy@qy-desktop:~$
```

PS I am sorry if this is repost. I am loosing track of my posts...

Comment: "_I am loosing track of my posts._" click on your name and then choose Activity. It looks like you haven't learned how to accept people's answers. Please do so with the tick-mark next to the best answer for each of your questions.

Comment: Related - [temporary removing device /partition from RAID5 - getting "Device or resource busy"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684945/100397)

Comment: I'm confused why you're mixing /dev/sdf23 with /dev/sdc; your title is possibly a typo of "x" for "c" (next to each other on a QWERTY keyboard). Can you [edit] your post to describe your specific problem?

Comment: I am asking how to unbusy a device - it should not matter what makes it busy - but in this case it is a /dev/sdx  ( x being a thru y) and it shows as RAID in lsblk.It was / is a part of RAID which is no longer accessible. I am trying to add it to a new RAID , but cannot because it is  busy. The idea of the old post was to identify what makes the device busy - and go from there...